# how to add text to textarea w/ javascript but still be able to type in it afterwards?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am trying to add text to a textarea in javascript, but, before you mark this as a duplicate, it doesn't allow me to add more text inside the textarea after I've typed anything else in there.

```js
var f1t = true;

var foo = function() {
  if (f1t === true) {
    document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML += "<i:>"
    f1t = false
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML += "<:>"
    f1t = true
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea> <button onclick="foo();">+</button>
```

When this code is ran, it will put as many things inside the textarea as I want until I type something. Then, when the function is called, it wont put anything in the textarea and wont throw any errors. I want to be able to continuously add text to the textarea even after I've typed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innerHTML of a textarea describes it's **default value** and not its **current value**. Once the user types something, it's default value is irrelevant (unless you have a reset button).

Set the `value` property instead.

Comment: I used a similar method earlier in my project. I can't believe I forgot it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

```js
var f1t = true,
    foo = function() {
      document.getElementById("textarea").value += f1t ? "<i:>" : "<:>";
      f1t = !f1t;
    };
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea> <button onclick="foo();">+</button>
```